# Where does JControllerLegacy::redirect() redirect to?

Tags: redirect, controller

I'm trying to understand the tutorial at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_view_to_the_site_part,
but I don't understand the last line of code (`$controller->redirect();`).

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_helloworld
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by HelloWorld
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('HelloWorld');

// Perform the Request task
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$controller->execute($input->getCmd('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

I looked at https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.MVC.Controller.BaseController.html#method_redirect to find what this `redirect()` actually does, but it does nothing and just returns a boolean value or maybe I am misunderstanding.

I wonder where this `redirect()` leads to. Does this `redirect()` follow certain rules that I didn't yet see? Does `redirect()` lead to a fixed URL?.

Answer (score 1):

It redirects to whatever is set in controller's `$redirect` property, normally using `setRedirect()` method.

As an example, redirects are commonly used in form controllers. When saving an item fails, you are usually redirected back to the form. And when saving succeeds, you are redirected to a list of items.

Comment: could you please point me to an example about usage of this `setRedirect()` ?

Comment: A random example https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/29d345b00a8173dbfb332215dd3513437f7a9a1f/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/FormController.php#L758-L766.